# Google+ Auth in AWS Cognito and API Gateway is unauthorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

AWS Wizards,

I've created a POC web app to test `AWS Cognito` and `Federated Identities` for a project.

I extended the POC with `Google+ authentication`. When a user authenticates via Google the counter for the Google Signin is increasing in Federated Identities, they are obviously being verified.

Now I am trying to use the credentials with a secured `AWS API Gateway` endpoint with no luck. The user will remain unauth'ed according to the gateway. I've tried the test feature in the API Gateway authorizers config, if I test with a Cognito user `CognitoUserSession.idToken` the test returns the claims.

If I do the same test with a Google user's `idToken` it is unauthenticated. After a successful Google sign in the same AWS Javascript SDK code is executed (as the Cognito user login). The credentials are updated with an identity ID and a session token but no ID token.

As I am a total noob on AWS I am probably missing something here. What should I do to get a valid idToken? Should it be done in a different way?

([GoogleLogin](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login) is a React component)

```js
render() {
    return (
        <GoogleLogin
            clientId="44xxx11.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            buttonText="Google Login"
            onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
            onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
        />
    )
}

responseGoogle(response) {
    console.log(response.tokenId)
    cognitoIdentityCredentials(response.tokenId)
}

cognitoIdentityCredentials(idToken) {

    const loginsObj = {
        ['accounts.google.com']: idToken
    }

    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // your identity pool id here
        Logins: loginsObj
    })

    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("---- AWS credentials ----")
            console.log(AWS.config.credentials)
            // Got credentials, but no valid idToken
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: that code seems ok, but there is no code that calls Lambda... and the problem seems to be there...

Comment: Why should I call a Lambda on the client side?

Comment: "Now I am trying to use the credentials with a secured AWS API Gateway endpoint with no luck"...

Comment: We are testing the credentials with Postman according to AWS own documentation, but if you have a code example how to make a request with the AWS SDK I'm more than happy to test it.

Comment: you need to sign the requests with something like https://github.com/mhart/aws4

Comment: After federating with Google using the Cognito Federated Identities, you will get IdentityId and temporary AWS credentials but no idToken. When using Cognito User pools you get a idToken.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is that you can't really use AWS Security the way I assumed. In AWS API Gateway a generated library can be downloaded to access that API specifically and when using the lib we found that there are more fields added to the request, and yes they are signed. All of them.

It will be a pain to use different SDK libraries for different environments and apps, so we simply took one of the SDKs and made it into a general library that we can use for all requests in all web projects. There are similar projects already on Github, but they are unfortunately only working with Cognito users, not Federated Identities.

Happy Panda again.